# Make my application only running app

Tags: android

I am making an android application and I want that it would be the only application running. No other application can run while my application is running.
How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dare say, that is a bad idea!

Comment: Can not be done! Android is design that way! Do you think people would even use such an app?

Comment: There's security reasons this can not be done.  Having that power would be a tojan's golden goose.  If you want this done for legit enterprise reasons, then you need to compile your own version of Android that only loads the programs you want and disables the installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why so greedy? You are never the only app to run. This totally goes against the entire design of Android. Instead of your app being the only one to run, you can make it a better "citizen." There are plenty of Google IO videos that talk about app optimization.